# Popup div broken

Tags: javascript, css

I have a popup I found online. The problem is the popup div is clickable for some reason. Can anyone help me fix this please. The actual text inside is clickable even though it is not a link. Thanks

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
user-select: none;  
-webkit-user-select: none; 
}

.popup .popuptext {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
border-radius: 6px;
color: red;
left: 0px;
margin-left: -80px;
padding: 8px 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 125%;
visibility: hidden;
width: 160px;
z-index: 1;
}

.popup .show {
animation: fadeIn 1s;
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/1/Bullhorn-1.png" title="Spread the word" 
onmouseover="this.src='https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/1/Bullhorn.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/1/Bullhorn-1.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what you mean that is clickable? PS: ctrl+c ctrl+v is not a good way to learn

Comment: I want the text inside to be just text. You run the mouse over it you can click anywhere on the div to close. I do not want that to happen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
user-select: none;  
-webkit-user-select: none; 
}

.popup .popuptext {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
border-radius: 6px;
color: red;
left: 0px;
padding: 8px 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 125%;
visibility: hidden;
width: 160px;
z-index: 1;
}

.popup .show {
animation: fadeIn 1s;
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup"  >
<!doctype html >
<object type="image/svg+xml">
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs></defs>
  <g>
    <g transform="matrix(0.4332926869, 0, 0, 0.3863767385, 11.0271053314, -22.4785881042)" style="">
      <path onclick="myFunction()" d="m497 241h-60c-8.291 0-15 6.709-15 15s6.709 15 15 15h60c8.291 0 15-6.709 15-15s-6.709-15-15-15z"></path>
      <path onclick="myFunction()" d="m432.254 181.776c-7.852 2.607-12.1 11.104-9.478 18.97 2.604 7.811 11.058 12.114 18.97 9.478l45-15c7.852-2.607 12.1-11.104 9.478-18.97-2.607-7.852-11.03-12.114-18.97-9.478z"></path>
      <path onclick="myFunction()" d="m477.254 345.224c7.905 2.635 16.364-1.661 18.97-9.478 2.622-7.866-1.626-16.362-9.478-18.97l-45-15c-7.925-2.607-16.362 1.626-18.97 9.478-2.622 7.866 1.626 16.362 9.478 18.97z"></path>
      <path onclick="myFunction()" d="m377 421c8.291 0 15-6.709 15-15v-300c0-8.291-6.709-15-15-15s-15 6.709-15 15v23.199c-25.508 24.001-57.378 40.371-91 47.523v158.555c33.622 7.152 65.492 23.522 91 47.523v23.2c0 8.291 6.709 15 15 15z"></path>
      <path onclick="myFunction()" d="m45 331h15v45c0 8.291 6.709 15 15 15h91c8.291 0 15-6.709 15-15v-45h50.142c3.314 0 6.573.311 9.858.48v-150.96c-3.285.168-6.544.48-9.858.48h-186.142c-24.814 0-45 20.186-45 45v60c0 24.814 20.186 45 45 45zm106 30h-61v-30h61z"></path>
    </g>
    <polyline style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" points="114.6 47.8 129.7 46.4 129.3 106.8 114.6 105 115 48.2"></polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
</object>
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Please check this

Comment: It does the same thing. I figured out the problem its the curser. I need the curser on the image but not the div box.

Comment: Please use clip-path for this solution
[https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/)
**[https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)**

Comment: please check again @jessie-williams

Answer (score 0):

```
.popup {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

This seems to be the culprit. You've provided the cursor:pointer; on the whole popup.